# Komodo Edit Markup and .htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, komodo, komodoedit

Just curious if any one know the best "file type" to use to get .htaccess file to work with Komodo Edit's markup short cuts.

Example: I want to comment a block of code, I highlight it and press CTRL+3. The markup is auto-added to comment out said block.

The problem, it doesn't add `#` at the beginning of each line, which of course is what I need.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- Open the `.htaccess` file.
- Look in lower right for the word `Text` with some arrows next to it

  - This is where you can change your file type on the fly (i do this a bunch)
- Click it and scroll down the menu that pops up to `Other`

  - Hold cursor there a second and a second menu will appear
- Near the top of the sub-menu that appeared is the word `Apache`

  - *Select it*!